# Make vector of elements less than each element of another vector

Tags: matlab

I have a vector, `v`, of N positive integers whose values I do not know ahead of time. I would like to construct another vector, `a`, where the values in this new vector are determined by the values in `v` according to the following rules: 
- The elements in `a` are all integers up to and including the value of each element in `v`
- 0 entries are included only once, but positive integers appear twice in a row

For example, if `v` is `[1,0,2]` then `a` should be: `[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,2,2]`.

Is there a way to do this without just doing a for-loop with lots of if statements?

I've written the code in loop format but would like a vectorized function to handle it.

Comment: FYI, \`text\` marks a section of text to be displayed in `code` markup. It's also a good idea to include your attempt at solving the problem you asked. In this case, it includes what you wrote in loop format. Sure it's obvious. But no one wants to spend the extra time to visualize it. And you've written it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classical version of your problem is to create a vector `a` with the concatenation of `1:n(i)` where `n(i)` is the ith entry in a vector `b`, e.g.

```
b = [1,4,2];
```

gives a vector `a`

```
a = [1,1,2,3,4,1,2];
```

This problem is solved using `cumsum` on a vector `ones(1,sum(b))` but resetting the sum at the points `1+cumsum(b(1:end-1))` corresponding to where the next sequence starts.

To solve your specific problem, we can do something similar. As you need two entries per step, we use a vector `0.5 * ones(1,sum(b*2+1))` together with `floor`. As you in addition only want the entry `0` to occur once, we will just have to start each sequence at `0.5` instead of at `0` (which would yield `floor([0,0.5,...]) = [0,0,...]`).

So in total we have something like

```
% construct the list of 0.5s
a = 0.5*ones(1,sum(b*2+1))

% Reset the sum where a new sequence should start
a(cumsum(b(1:end-1)*2+1)+1) =a(cumsum(b(1:end-1)*2+1)+1)*2 -(b(1:end-1)+1)

% Cumulate it and find the floor
a = floor(cumsum(a))
```

Note that all operations here *are* vectorised!

**Benchmark:**

You can do a benchmark using the following code

```
function SO()
b =randi([0,100],[1,1000]);

t1 = timeit(@() Nicky(b));
t2 = timeit(@() Recursive(b));
t3 = timeit(@() oneliner(b));

if all(Nicky(b) == Recursive(b)) && all(Recursive(b) == oneliner(b))
    disp("All methods give the same result")
else
    disp("Something wrong!")
end

disp("Vectorised time: "+t1+"s")
disp("Recursive time: "+t2+"s")
disp("One-Liner time: "+t3+"s")
end

function [a] = Nicky(b)
a = 0.5*ones(1,sum(b*2+1));
a(cumsum(b(1:end-1)*2+1)+1) =a(cumsum(b(1:end-1)*2+1)+1)*2 -(b(1:end-1)+1);
a = floor(cumsum(a));
end

function out=Recursive(arr)
    out=myfun(arr);
    function local_out=myfun(arr)
        if isscalar(arr)
            if arr
                local_out=sort([0,1:arr,1:arr]); % this is faster
            else
                local_out=0;
            end
        else
            local_out=[myfun(arr(1:end-1)),myfun(arr(end))];
        end
    end
end

function b = oneliner(a)
b = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)sort([0,1:x,1:x]),a,'UniformOutput',false));
end
```

Which gives me

```
All methods give the same result
Vectorised time: 0.00083574s
Recursive time: 0.0074404s
One-Liner time: 0.0099933s
```

So the vectorised one is indeed the fastest, by a factor approximately 10.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a one-liner using `eval`:

```
a = eval(['[' sprintf('sort([0 1:%i 1:%i]) ',[v(:) v(:)]') ']']);
```

Here is another solution that does not use eval. Not sure what is intended by "vectorized function" but the following code is compact and can be easily made into a function:

```
a = [];
for i = 1:numel(v)
    a = [a sort([0 1:v(i) 1:v(i)])];
end
```

Comment: `eval` =/= vectorization. Needless to say, avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this without just doing a for loop with lots of if statements?

Sure. How about recursion? Of course, there is no guarantee that Matlab has tail call optimization.

For example, in a file named `filename.m`

```
function out=filename(arr)
    out=myfun(in);
    function local_out=myfun(arr)
        if isscalar(arr)
            if arr
                local_out=sort([0,1:arr,1:arr]); % this is faster
            else
                local_out=0;
            end
        else
            local_out=[myfun(arr(1:end-1)),myfun(arr(end))];
        end
    end
end
```

in cmd, type

```
input=[1,0,2];
filename(input);
```

You can take off the parent function. I added it just hoping Matlab can spot the recursion within `filename.m` and optimize for it.

> would like a vectorized function to handle it.

Sure. Although I don't see the point of vectorizing in such a unique puzzle that is not generalizable to other applications. I also don't foresee a performance boost.

For example, assuming input is 1-by-N. In cmd, type

```
input=[1,0,2];
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)sort([0,1:x,1:x]),input,'UniformOutput',false)
```

---

### Benchmark

In R2018a

```
>> clear all
>> in=randi([0,100],[1,100]); N=10000;

>> T=zeros(N,1);tic; for i=1:N; filename(in) ;T(i)=toc;end; mean(T),
ans =
    1.5647

>> T=zeros(N,1);tic; for i=1:N; cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)sort([0,1:x,1:x]),in,'UniformOutput',false)); T(i)=toc;end; mean(T),
ans =
    3.8699
```

Ofc, I tested with a few more different inputs. The 'vectorized' method is always about twice as long.

Conclusion: Recursion is faster.

Comment: `arrayfun` is not vectorization. It's a disguised for loop, that just adds a bit of overhead. It's actually faster to explicitly write the loop instead of letting MATLAB figure out how to do it.

Comment: And vectorization can be useful if this is a task that's performed thousands or millions of times, and if the vectorization boosts performance. Loops in MATLAB are not as slow as they used to be, so vectorization is not always the way even when it's possible.

Comment: @StewieGriffin: I've tested in the past that `arrayfun` is at least faster by a constant amount. Do you have tests to show what you claimed? As for the argument re vectorization, I am not interested in a philosophical discussion unless the actual problem calls for serious thought on efficiency.

Comment: It might have been improved in the newer MATLAB versions, but it used to be faster. You have to write the loop optimally of course, remembering to initialize the vector/array etc. Vectorization is, if done correctly, usually quite a bit faster than loops/arrayfun. Typically, if you have solved with the combination of `bsxfun` (now obsolete), `permute` and `reshape` then you have vectorized it. And it will be fun.

Comment: @StewieGriffin To me, that just means you've defined 'vectorization' to be using `bsxfun` and the like. The interesting part of the test is that Matlab may have implemented tail call optimization after all. (Oh let me edit in my version number.) If you try messing the code to make it so that some output is not written to `local_out`, the code can still be valid. e.g. make the `else` case write to a variable in the parent function. But Matlab throws an error.